# FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly System.IO.Ports

Tags: c#, filenotfoundexception, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

Yesterday I've worked on a project and got this exception:

> **`System.IO.FileNotFoundException`:** Could not load file or assembly. The system cannot find the file specified.

Then I've Googled for hours what the problem could be but didn't find a solution.

The weird thing is that I've started with a complete new .NET Core project today and I've installed the `Lego.Ev3` NuGet library and got the same error again.

This is my code, the exception will thrown on the last line:

```
using Lego.Ev3.Core;
using Lego.Ev3.Desktop;

Brick brick = new Brick(new BluetoothCommunication("COM10"));
```

This are more details of the exception in my Lego<sup>©</sup> project:

> **`System.IO.FileNotFoundException`:** Could not load file or assembly `System.IO.Ports, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51`. The system cannot find the file specified.**

Is there a setting wrong in Visual Studio?

Comment: Have you checked whether the specified path and file actually exists?

Comment: Does `Lego.Ev3` have Standard/Core support? Maybe it is running framework, and have library dependencies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`System.IO.Ports` is **not** available in .NET Core.
It's only available in .NET Framework 4.8.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports

As a possible solution, try to create a project with .NET Framework 4.8, not with .NET Core.

Comment: Thanks, that was my issue - a Core app trying to reference an old DLL that referenced IO.Ports...

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for answering an old question, but I got around this by adding System.IO.Ports nuget package.

I wasn't working with the Lego library, so I don't know if it's a fix for that specifically, but it worked for the library I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to communicate using SerialPort with a LTE Module on a RaspberryPi using c#/.net core. I had the nuget package "System.IO.Ports" installed, but when I scp:ed the files to the RaspberryPi, I missed to include the folder "runtimes" in the publish folder, it contains the native code that is needed for it to work.